# Why does css mix-blend-mode: color; cover all colors except white instead of all colors except white and black?

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to figure out why the `mix-blend-mode: color;` css selector and value affects all colors except white instead of affecting all colors except white and black.  Can someone pls explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#valdef-blend-mode-color):

> color blend mode
>   Creates a color with the **hue and saturation** of the *source color* and the **luminosity** of the *backdrop color*. This preserves the gray levels of the backdrop and is useful for coloring monochrome images or tinting color images.

So we need to consider the `hsl()` color and for the white we will have `hsl(x, y, 100%)` and for black we will have `hsl(x, y, 0%)` (whataver the values of x,y). So if your background (the backdrop color) is white or black then the result color will be white or black since will keep the luminosity and whataver the value of hue and saturation we will always have white or black.

```css
img {
  mix-blend-mode:color;
  display:block;
}
div {
  border:1px solid green;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div >
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/150">
</div>
<div style="background:#fff;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/150">
</div>
<div style="background:#000;">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/150">
</div>
```

Now if we consider that our color will always be black or white. In this case the hue saturation of the black/white will be used and we keep the luminosity of the backdrop color. Generally we define the hue and saturation of white and black to be 0 so we will end having `hsl(0,0%,z)` where `z` will depend on the background image. This means that we will have the same result (a grey image) if we consider black or white as color:

```css
div.box {
  border:1px solid green;
  display:inline-block;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/150);
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
}
div.box > div {
  mix-blend-mode:color;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div style="background:#fff"></div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div style="background:#000"></div>
</div>
```